# Java Syntax: JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj

Tags: java, arrays, json, syntax, json-simple

I'm learning to Decode JSON files in Java and have come across some Syntax I do not understand.  I am also new to Java. Here is the code snippet:

```
Object obj = JSONValue.parse(jsonResult);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
```

In my best attempt at Programmer speak, I understand that "JSONArray" is a class. We are instantiating a new JSONArray and calling it "array". We are initializing "array" with the value on the right side of the equal sign.

My question is -- I don't understand what is happening on the right side of the equal sign. Why is "JSONArray" in parenthesis: (JSONArray)obj? I don't understand what is happening here.

Thanks!

Comment: Java objects don't have names. `array` is a reference, and `obj` is a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received JSON may, as its outermost structure, be either an "object" (Map) or "array" (List).  `JSONValue.parse(jsonResult)` produces either a JSONObject or JSONArray, depending on which sort of structure is outermost in the `jsonResult` string.  So the `parse` method must be declared to return some common "ancestor" of those two classes.  JSON-Simple is a rather crude JSON kit which has no common superclass for those two classes other than Object.

Presumably the programmer in this case knows that the received data will always have a JSON "array" as the outermost structure.  He initially puts the result from `parse` in an Object reference (since Object is the formal type returned from `parse`), then casts that value to JSONArray.

As Eliot suggests, it would have been better, formally, at least, to include an `instanceof` test, or, if one used a kit other than JSON-Simple, one could possibly make use of interfaces on a common superclass for the two classes that allowed querying their types.

Answer (score 0):

That is an example of an (unchecked) type-cast. I suggest you use a checked cast using the type comparison operator [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) first. Something like,

```
JSONArray array = null;
Object obj = JSONValue.parse(jsonResult);
if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
    array = (JSONArray)obj;
}
```

If you're certain it will always be a `JSONArray` you might do it in one line like

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parse(jsonResult);
```

The reason it's necessary to cast at all is because the result of `parse()` is an `Object`.